# Tools for programming in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I'm working with XML and XSLT by following these steps:
 
1) I open a XML file with Microsoft Word;
2) Then I select an XSLT style sheet, by the "Browse" button;
3) an output is created in Microsoft Word;

Question:
There is a tool/application that allows you to **see step by step the application of xslt to xml**, as is the case for debugging visual basic. 
A tool that allows you to put a stop to block the execution of the application and see the output of xslt what created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a lot more Options, but those are I think the most prominent:

**[Oxygen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/download_oxygenxml_editor.html):**
This is one of the (if not THE) most full featured XML/XSLT Development Environment you can get, they have good documentation on how to use their xslt debugger, for more information check out http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xslt_debugger.html

**[Altova XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/):**
Similar to Oxygen, XML focused development environment, description of their debugger can be found at http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xslt-debugger.html

**[Microsoft Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718325.aspx):**
This is obviously not as fully featured as the straight up XML Development Environments mentioned before, but since you mentioned working with Visual Basic you might allready have it. You will find some information on how to use it to debug XSLT at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255602(v=vs.110).aspx

**[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/):** is also able to edit and debug XSLT. I never used it for XSLT Development, but since it is free it might actually be a good option, you can checkout its XSLT specific tools at: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xsl.doc%2Fhtml%2Flaunching%2Flaunching.html

Answer (score 1):

There are various XML IDEs like Oxygen, Stylus Studio or AltovaXML Spy that come with a debugger. Visual Studio in the commercial editions also comes with a debugger to debug stylesheets executed with the .NET framework's XslCompiledTransform.

Comment: Thanks Martin Honnen.